# How to fix "Error computing CMake server result." error in Android?

Tags: cmake, java-native-interface, dlib, android, opencv

I'm working on Android Studio with native library. My main goal is import dlib and opencv to Android as a native library. I follow this instruction : Here's [link](https://medium.com/@luca_anzalone/setting-up-dlib-and-opencv-for-android-3efdbfcf9e7f)!

But I have encountered an error like this,

*Error computing CMake server result.
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done*

---

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error computing CMake server result.
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done

```
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:704)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:671)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
... 35 more
```

Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error computing CMake server result.
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Cevdet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done

```
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.executeProcessAndGetOutput(CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:237)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.CmakeExternalNativeJsonGenerator.executeProcess(CmakeExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:108)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildForOneConfiguration(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:316)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildAndPropagateException(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:212)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.build(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:149)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.build(ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
... 73 more
```

What should I do ?

Comment: _"I have encountered an error like this"_ I don't see any errors in the logs you've posted.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question.